# Highcharts - Export with background color

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to export my chart , with "white" background color. But always it is rendered with background as black (black color is nowhere in my page/code actually). I don't know from where the black color comes during download. Can someone help please. Attaching the "exporting" tag below

```
exporting: {
                chartOptions: { // specific options for the exported image
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        },
                        chart: {
                            events: {
                                load: function () {
                                    globalBackground = '#fff';
                                    this.plotBackground.attr({
                                        fill: globalBackground
                                    });
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                fallbackToExportServer: false,
                sourceWidth: 600,
                sourceHeight: 400
            }
```

Comment: Just adding that code doesn't make the background black during export. Please provide an example showing the error, for example on JSFiddle.

Comment: Do you use official exporting tool or your own? Could you recreate your example or supply whole chart configuration (including series) ?

Comment: psst -- the black color may be from "null" background which I believe is interpreted as black when exported to JPG... not sure if that's a highcharts thing or a jpg thing

Answer (score 5):

Probably you have chart backgroundColor = null. It means your chart has a transparent background. While exporting jpeg Highcharts renders transparent background as black. If you want to change the color while exporting set background color in exporting object.

```
exporting: {
  chartOptions: {
    chart: {
      backgroundColor: '#9E9E9E'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have a different background color on PNG and JPG files?

Comment: How to i programatically change its background color the button i mean?